# Not getting alert in SwiftUI from scenePhase change on app re-entering active state

Tags: ios, swiftui

Here is my example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @State var showAlert: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Testing alert when entering foreground")
        .padding()
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Alert!"))
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newValue in
            print("OnChange: Test: from onChange")
            switch newValue {
            case .active:
                print("OnChange: Test: active")
                //DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    showAlert = true
                //}
            case .background, .inactive:
                print("OnChange: Test: \(showAlert)")
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Only when I uncomment the `DispatchQueue.main.async` does the alert show up when the app re-enters the foreground. Note that the alert shows up the first time the app launches with or without the `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

This does not seem like a general problem of updating the UI from the `.onChange(of: scenePhase)` handler because the alert shows up on the first launch with the code above.

Further, with the following example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @State var foregroundCount = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if foregroundCount > 3 {
                Text("Entered foreground.")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newValue in
            print("OnChange: Test: from onChange")
            switch newValue {
            case .active:
                print("OnChange: Test: active")
                foregroundCount += 1
            case .background, .inactive:
                break
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The text will display on the 4th entry into the foreground.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can't tell exactly what is causing this but the behaviour you are observing could be due to the order of execution and timing of updates in SwiftUI's view lifecycle.
SwiftUI's behaviour can vary depending on the specific circumstances and timing of view updates.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because in the first code sample you didn't call the showAlert getter anywhere so SwiftUIs dependency tracking doesn't think you want body recomputed when showAlert is set. Workaround it with

```
.onChange(of: scenePhase) { [showAlert] newValue in
    ...
    self.showAlert =
```